# Python get return value on else statement, default variable equivalent to Perl $_

Tags: python, return-value

If I want to do something like the following, how can I get the return value from Is_Programmer() on the else block without calling the function again?

```
def Is_Programmer():
    if name.lower() == "gregg":
        input = raw_input("What is the point of this app?: ")
        My_Point = Pointless(input)
        return input
    else:
        return False
if Is_Programmer() == False:
    print "I am not going to ask you what the point of this app is, because you didn't write it"
else:
    answer = Return value from Is_Programmer()
```

**Full "Program" with suggested Solution**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Practicing Python with random programming.

name = raw_input("What are you called?:")

class Pointless(object):
    def __init__(self,point):
        self.point = point
        print "The point of this app, according to %s is ...%s" % (name, "\n" + self.point)

def Is_Programmer():
    if name.lower() == "gregg":        
        input = raw_input("What is the point of this app?: ")        
        My_Point = Pointless(input)
        return input
    else:
        return False
IP=Is_Programmer()
if IP == False:
    print "I am not going to ask you what the point of this app is, because you didn't write it"
else:
    answer = IP
s = name + " thinks the point of this app is\n" + answer + "\n"
f = open('Pointless.txt', 'w')
f.write(s)
f.close
```

Comment: Please, start with correcting indentation. As for your question - is there anything wrong with assigning result of function call to a variable? BTW You shouldn't call variable `input`. `input` is a Python builtin.

Comment: As a side note, instead of checking "foo == False", it's almost always better to just check "not foo". See PEP 8 for more info.

Comment: Also, why are you computing something and storing it in a local variable, My_Point, that you never use?

Comment: @abamert, Pointless is a class, this is just a code snippet, zero323 I have trouble getting things to format easily on this site, I tried to correct it.  I am just beginning with python and am not a programmer, so I am learning from the bottom.

Comment: @zero323: I agree of course, one shouldn't hide builtins. But since this code is Python2, of all the builtins you could hide, hiding access to the builtin `input` is probably a good thing :-)

Comment: @GreggLeventhal: when you need a special-case value in Python, `None` is pretty much always a better choice than `False` because it's what other programmers expect.

Comment: [Explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).  It is a design decision in Python to not have a default variable like in Perl.

Comment: I added the full code for context, maybe I'll learn something from everyone picking it apart.  It is a stupid program just for practice.

Comment: While you can certainly return text in one case and None (or False) in another in python, do you really want your code to read as though two different types are being returned. That imposes an unnecessary burden on the client AND couples that "peculiar" (IMO) implementation to any client code. (It has what Fowler would call a code smell.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.  Instead, call the function before the `if` and store the result.

```
isIt = Is_Programmer()
if isIt == False:
    print "Is not a programmer"
else:
    print isIt, "is the point"
```

Comment: Perhaps it should be `if not isIt:`?

Comment: I used this solution, it works well in the absence of a $_ type operator.

Comment: @SethMMorton: remember that the empty string tests as false. So the test `if not isIt` treats an empty string (entered by the programmer whose name is `gregg`) the same as a return value of `False` (that is, the case where the name is not `gregg`). That *might* be what you want, but then again it might not be. The fact that you intuitively want to change code to avoid comparing equal to False, though, is a good reason why the program shouldn't be returning `False` as a special case to begin with :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to say, but I am guessing you are letting me know that `isIt == False` is equivalent to `not isIt`.  I am aware of that... I was saying it should be `if not isIt:` because that is idiomatic python.  In fact, [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) explicitly says to do that instead of comparing equality to `False`.

Comment: @SethMMorton: They are not equivalent.  `if not isIt` will execute the `if` block if `isIt` is an empty string, but `if isIt==False` will only execute it if `isIt` is actually the value `False`.

Comment: @SethMMorton: That's good advice assuming vaguely conventional APIs, basically on the assumption that you only look to see whether a value is `False` if the value must take one of two values, `True` or `False`. More relevant in this case is another piece of advice from PEP 8: "Also, beware of writing `if x` when you really mean `if x is not None` ... The other value might have a type (such as a container) that could be false in a boolean context!". In this case, `if not isIt` is *not* equivalent to `if isIt == False` for that exact reason, with `False` standing in for `None` as a special value

Comment: ... basically, the set of values that are false in a boolean context varies between languages, and it's something you just have to learn and try not to fall foul of, especially when new to a language or if you switch languages a lot. The only sensible conclusion I can draw from this fact is that *at most* one of those differing languages is well-designed in this respect ;-) I'm not a C# programmer, but I have a sneaking suspicion that C# might be the one that's well-designed. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @BrenBarn I see now.  I was under the false impression (no pun intended) that `'' == False` would evaluate to `True`, and that if you wanted to test if something was in fact the boolean `False` you needed to use `is`, not `==`.  I should really test my assumptions out before making these assertions.

Answer (score -1):

```
return (True, input)
# else
return (False, None)

# then receive the values back
(isProg, text) = Is_Programmer ()
if isProg:
    # do something with text
else:
    # do something that did not need text
```

Edited since apparently somebody did not get the gist of the first 3 lines.